# c printf size_t

Tags: c, string, printf, size-t

My code compiles, though the `printf` doesn't display anything?

If I take out the formatter part of the `printf` then it works just fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t MyStrlen(const char *s1)
{
    const char *s1Copy = s1;

    while (*s1)
    {
        *s1Copy++;
    }

    return s1Copy -s1;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char str[] = "HELLO";

    printf("Length: %d \n", (unsigned int)MyStrlen(str));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think using `%u` without needing to cast the result is fine.

Comment: @chris Not really, that'll break if `size_t` and `unsigned` aren't the same size.

Comment: @Mysticial, Oh, duh, right. The `%u` should hold, though.

Comment: In addition, `*s1Copy++` is a waste - there's no need to dereference, just use `s1Copy++`. And the correct way (since C99) to print out a `size_t` is by using the `z` length modifier such as with `"%zd"`. `size_t` and any of the `int`-class types may be totally different widths. And I won't even _begin_ to ask what you think is wrong with the stdlib `strlen` that would require you to write you own :-)

Comment: Please don't change questions to the point where answers become totally invalid - that makes the entire Q&A useless. If you fix the started problem and there's a different issue, ask _another_ question.

Comment: Whoops, I rolled back to the wrong version. It should be ok now (i.e., the question now contains the problem that pb2q's answer explains). Jason, pb2q's answer says "In your loop test you'll want to test `*s1Copy` for non-NULL, not `*s1`, which you aren't incrementing." That's the *only* thing you really need to fix.

Answer (score 9):

In your loop test you want to test `*s1Copy` for non-NULL, not `*s1`, which you aren't incrementing. As it is, since `*s1` never changes, you're walking right off the end of your string argument with `s1Copy++` and the code won't terminate normally.

Unless of course you pass the empty string: your `MyStrlen` method **will** work for the empty string.

```
while (*s1Copy)
    s1Copy++;
```

Comment: +1 nice catch when everyone seems to be discussing size_t ;-)

Comment: As a nitpick, the code _may_ work fine. Calculating pointer differences when they're not both part of an array or just one beyond the array is undefined behaviour. Though it would be unlikely to work, sometimes UB will. That's its most annoying propoerty. If only UB could deliver a few amps to the coder's genitalia consistently, there'd be a lot fewer bugs :-)

Answer (score 5):

This:

```
printf("Length: %d \n", (unsigned int)MyStrlen(str));
```

is ok; `%d` expects an `int` argument, but it's guaranteed that `int` and `unsigned int` have the same representation for values that are in the range of both.  This:

```
printf("Length: %u\n", (unsigned int)MyStrlen(str));
```

is better, since `%u` expects an `unsigned int` argument.

The correct format for `size_t` is `"%zu"`:

```
printf("Length: %zu\n", MyStrlen(str));
```

but this is a "new" feature in C99, and there are likely still some implementations that don't support it.  (In particular, Microsoft has been very slow to support C99.) For maximum portability (assuming your string is no more than 2<sup>32</sup>-1 bytes long) you can use this:

```
printf("Length: %lu\n", (unsigned long)MyStrlen(str));
```

This answers the question you asked about `printf`; pb2q ably diagnosed the actual cause of the problem you're seeing (and beat me to it!).

Comment: +1 for the `z` length modifier. I don't know _why_ most C coders (other than embedded developers who may not have a choice) are still stuck in the world from 20 years ago. Come, join us, you know you want to :-)

Comment: now my printf kinda of works though the length of the string is always 0<br/>

Comment: @paxdiablo: Microsoft must take some of the blame; Visual C++ 2010 doesn't recognize `"%zu"`. Microsoft has expressed a distinct lack of interest in supporting C99.

Comment: @Jason: By updating your code, you've removed the problem, and made pb2q's answer obsolete. In effect, you're now asking a different question.

Comment: why does *s1Copy return a value of 0

Comment: @Jason: Because `s1Copy` points to the terminating null character `'\0'` of your string, and `*s1Copy` returns the value of that characters, which is `0`. The previous version of `s1Copy` was much closer to being correct. I'm going to revert your edit.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14319/discussion-between-jason-and-keith-thompson)